# Substring match from one data frame to another

Tags: python, dataframe, substring

I have a two Data Frame A and B. i want to search the substring in A Value column and if the value is match with B Value column , then create new data frame C with new values.
for example ,'valid username' of substring 'user' match with input_txtuserid, then it will replace
valid username.

A=

```
  Value                           
 "valid username"           
 "Password"                 
 "Login"                     
 "Navigates"
 "productcode"
 "booking details"
 "Source"
```

B=

```
Value                          Filed        
input_txtuserid                  "JOHN"
input_txtpassword                 "78945"
input_submit_log_in              "Sucessfully"
txtProduct                         "IPhone"
```

I want my data frame to look like this:

B=

```
Value                          Filed        
valid username                 "JOHN"
Password                        "78945"
Login                           "Sucessfully"
productcode                         "IPhone"
```

Comment: You need to rethink about your criteria of matching. `"valid username"` matches with `"input_txtuserid"` for substring `user`, it also matches with `"input_txtpassword"` for substrings `i, s, d` and so many. SO you need to be specific about what substring you want to match everytime.

Comment: any other criteria  to match only user ,password or Product